# How to display two differents models in my view with will_paginate in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, display, will-paginate

Hi everyone I have a question , I looking for on google but I don't find an answer.
I'm actually want to display Post model and User model by search in same page and for this I want to use Will_paginate to display all of them .
**I try this solution =>**

```
  **require 'will_paginate/array'
  @posts =Post.search(params[:q]).order("created_at DESC")
  @users=User.search(params[:q]).order("created_at DESC")
    @all_records = (@posts + @users).paginate(:page =>params[:page], :per_page => 10)**
```

And In my view I want to display all query found ,so I try something like this =>

```
 **<%unless @posts.nil?%>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  ....
**
**<% unless @users.nil?%>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
...**
<%= will_paginate @all_records %>
```

But it doesn't work nothing happend, so I want to know how to get @posts and @users records in @all_records to do something like this =>
**

```
<% @all_records[@posts].each do.. %>
<% @all_records[@usets].each do ..%>
```

**
I saw some solutions that suggest to use two differentes paginate in my view like =>

```
**<%= will_paginate @posts %>
<%= will_paginate @users %>**
```

**But It's not want I want , I would'like only one paginate for all, Please Help me cause I'm going crazy, Thank you **

Comment: I follow this tutoriel http://railsforbeginners.com/chapters/chapter-9-infinite-scroll/ cause I think it's easier to display two models paginations using ajax infinite scroll but nothing happen , my controller doesn't go in my index.js.erb and I don't know why , I try to change position values but nothing help please